# What's event `mouseenter.zoom'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm a beginner JavaScript programmer. While I was reading the source code of [jQuery Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) (a jQuery plugin), I saw the author defined a handler for event [`mouseenter.zoom`](https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/blob/master/jquery.zoom.js#L165).

I know there's an event called `mouseenter` but can't find `mouseenter.zoom`. Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event, but it is using [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

The namespaces are used normally to refer to a particular event handler so that it can be individually removed later.

#### Example

```
$('<selector>').on('mouseenter.zoom', function(){});
```

later to remove the handler

```
$('<selector>').off('mouseenter.zoom');
```

If you look at the end of the plugin there is `$(source).off(".zoom");` it means remove all the event handlers with namespace `zoom`, it is an easier method to destroy the plugin than removing each event handler individually.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time explaining when the links in your first paragraph already answered my question perfectly. A follow-up question: the `$(source).off('.zoom')` code is wrapped inside an event handler for `zoom.destroy` -- when does that event happen?

Comment: @JohnN it is another event handler, I assume you need to invoke it if you want it using the `trigger('')` method